# Conditional rendering decimal codes in JSX in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to render an **✕ and ✓**, conditionally with JSX, but this approach doesn't work.

```
<div>{exists ? &#10003; : &#10005;}</div>
```

What would be the right solution for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap that using `span` and span should have an attribute of  `role="img"` otherwise React will show warning.

```
<div>{true ? <span role="img">&#10003;</span> : <span role="img">&#10005;</span>}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code:

```
{exists ? <div>&#10005;</div> : <div>&#10003;</div>}
```